# Swift: CollectionView cells not displaying until view is refreshed

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uibutton

The view is constructed with 4 navigation buttons that toggle which collection views are displayed. I want the "friends" cells to be displayed when the screen is first launched

As of now. The view will not display any collection until one of the navigation buttons are selected or the page is refreshed using the swift refreshControl.

Here are two images showing what the screen looks like when it is first loaded and after the friends navigation button is clicked

[image]

*note this is only a portion of the file because it is very large with many trivial functions for this issue... If you would like to see a .zip or other functions please let me know.*

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        backgroundView.layer.addBorder(edge: .bottom, color: .lightGray, thickness: 1)
        backgroundView.addViewGradient()
        setupViews()
        registerCells()
        loadBuckets()
        handledFriendsBtnTap()
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        refresh()
    }
    
    private func refresh(){
        refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refresh(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        collectionView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    }
    private func registerCells() {
        collectionView.register(FriendNotificationCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "FriendCellId")
        collectionView.register(CommentNotificationCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CommentCellId")
        collectionView.register(LikeNotificationCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "LikeCellId")
        collectionView.register(InspirationNotificationCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "InspirationCellId")
    }

    @objc func refresh(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
    
    @objc func handledFriendsBtnTap(){
        friendsBtn.addSubview(selectionDot)
        selectionDot.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: friendsBtn.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        selectionDot.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: friendsBtn.bottomAnchor, constant: -6).isActive = true
        selectionDot.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 5).isActive = true
        selectionDot.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 5).isActive = true
        
        if friendArray.count == 0 {
            collectionView.addSubview(noContentLabel)
            noContentLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.centerYAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
            noContentLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        } else {
            noContentLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        
        pageIndex = 0
        screenLaunch = false
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        
    }


extension NotificationsVC: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if pageIndex == 0{
            return setupFriendCell(indexPath: indexPath)
        }else if pageIndex == 1{
            return setupCommentCell(indexPath: indexPath)
        }else if pageIndex == 2{
            return setupLikeCell(indexPath: indexPath)
        }else if pageIndex == 3 {
            return setUpInspirationCell(indexPath: indexPath)
        }
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if pageIndex == 0 {
            return self.friendArray.count
        } else if pageIndex == 1 {
            return self.commentArray.count
        }else if pageIndex == 2 {
            return self.likeArray.count
        }else if pageIndex == 3 {
            return self.inspirationArray.count
        }
        return 0
    }
```

Comment: Where does your friend data come from? My guess is you're making an async network request, the data hasn't yet returned, and you aren't reloading the collection view when that data does return.

Comment: correct is is a firestore querry.  The function is defined in another file then called in this one, which loads the array, etc... Would I call the refresh after the data is returned within this file?

Comment: If you're fetching data from Firestore, when the page is loaded and you're fetching data, you should instead display a "Loading" indicator. Then once you get a response, you would refresh the friends collection view

Comment: not related to the question but found that you are adding refresh control everytime viewwillappear is called.

Comment: @Joshua thanks for pointing that out. I'm new to ios development, what is the proper way to implement a refresh control?

Comment: if collectionview's is created manually I usually add it in the initalization part having it lazily and assigning it like this `collection.refreshControl = refreshControl` 

If the collectionview is added using xib/interface builder I would suggestion adding it in the viewdidload. I usually create views programmatically though.

 
And it's a different topic I would say.